# How to align multiple items below each other in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I'm creating an app with `Meteor` using [`alethes:pages`](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages) package for the pagination and `Bootstrap 3` for the styles.
In the main page I'm displaying multiple items (3 per row) using infinite scroll.

The problem comes when an item is higher than his neighbour items, making the next row to have a free space and floating one item to the right, instead of appearing below the higher one. Here you can see the problem:

[image: One of the items is floated to the right, showing a free space]

I made an HTML template for the item to be used by the pagination package.
So, for the example shown in the image, the generated code will be this one:

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="pagesCont">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/jvtQWo4KSziMXCryh/300x340.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 1 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 2 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 3 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 4 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 5 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 6</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 6 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 7</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 7 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 8</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 8 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 well">
                <h4 class="break-word">
                    <a href="#">Item 9</a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/cfs/files/images_publications/woTuL4hS6SkSYRSb3/300x300.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJsQU55dkttNWNxR0twVjJDWmpad1kzMHhOYS1IMGhTNDdiV0t5Vjd4M1lDIn0%3D&amp;store=images_publications" alt="NO VA" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 break-word">
                    <a href="#">Category</a>
                </h5>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> 9 €</h4>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="break-word">UserName UserLastName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could make the items to have the same hight but I want to have different image sizes and multiline text without leaving free space inside the item.

I want something like the items list shown in this web: http://es.wallapop.com/

But the problem with that list is that uses absolute positions in order to display an item below each other. I would like to avoid absolute positions since I think it wouldn't be so easy to integrate with the package mentioned before.

I don't know if something like this is possible in `Bootstrap 3` without using absolute positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little to do with meteor or pagination I believe.

What you are looking for is to probably implement masonyjs with bootstrap. Layouts like these can get really interesting and tricky. I would definitely look into that combo.

Comment: Yes, you are right about Meteor and Pagination. I wanted to be very detailed, sorry. Right now I'm trying to include `masonry` to make it work with `bootstrap` but it's getting hard. Thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: We can probably help with that too :) if you run into trouble with the masonry, you can always edit that into your question if you'd like.

Comment: Well, first let me mark you answer as the accepted one. Now, my current problem is related to Meteor, since I have to wrap the Masonry configuration in a `Meteor.setTimeout`  and add it to the `Template.rendered` function in order to be run after fetching the items and rendering them. And the `setTimeout` has to have a delay of 1.5 seconds more or less. Otherwise, Masonry gets crazy and overlaps all the items. I would like to able of runing Masonry right after fetching and rendering the items without using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Is the time out because the fetch is taking too long and the masonry is loading too early? I would assume so, but went to be sure.

Comment: The fetch takes a while and is realized by the `alethes:pages` package. I think the package fetches and renders the items after loading the page, using ajax.

Comment: {
    templateName: "PublicationsList",
    itemTemplate: "Publication",
    divWrapper: false,
    fastRender: true,
    infinite: true,
    sort: {
        createdAt: 1
    }
}

Comment: My guess (again, without testing personal) is you are grabbing a ton of stuff! How big is the collection? I realize you'd like infinite scrolling but you may want to play with  infiniteRateLimit and infiniteTrigger. You might even screw around with the infiniteItemsLimit setting to see if you can get load times down. Now after that you can play with your load settings. Maybe stick the whole thing into a Meteor.methods function and synchronously wait for that to finish before you load the masonry stuff. It should speed up page load.

Comment: It's not a big collection, it only has 15 records. I tried to tweak the pagination configuration like you said without success. I also tried to make a synchronous method (using `Meteor.wrapAsync`) to start the pagination but it didn't work. It would be awesome being able to call a callback function right after rendering the items but the package doesn't have such option as far as I know.

Comment: Well, I ended up doing the infinite scrolling manually and works really good with `Masonry` and `Isotope`. It's a shame not being able to use correctly the Meteor pages package with those libraries but at least I have something that works. Thank you very much for your help and for talk me about  `Masonry.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the conversation in the comments:

After a lot of research and testing I finally got `Masonry` to work perfectly with the [`alethes:pages`](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages) package. I know, in my last comment I said that I gave up on this, but after some time with my homemade infinite scroll I realized that it wasn't reacting to the mongodb changes, it was static. I didn't want to spend more time on that...

Before showing you the code that makes the magic you have to have some things in mind:

- The best way to use `Masonry` is by using `Isotope`, at least for me that was the case. I recommend you to install this meteor package:  [`isotope:isotope`](https://atmospherejs.com/isotope/isotope)
- You will also need the `ImagesLoadead` library: [`iamkevingreen:imagesloaded`](https://atmospherejs.com/iamkevingreen/imagesloaded)
- The `alethes:pages` package uses the `document.body.offsetHeight` DOM property as the total page height, in order to load new items when scrolling. If you are using `Bootstrap` that property may not represent the total page height, so every scroll made can add new items no matter what you set in the `infiniteTrigger` option. The way to fix this is by adding a `clearfix` before closing the body:

```html
    <template name="MasterLayout">
        ...
        {{> yield}}
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </template>
```

- The items container used by `Masonry` must have `padding: 0` (at least left and right) in order to be displayed correctly using `Bootstrap`.

Now, let's see the code.

This is the server code:

```js
Items =  new Meteor.Collection('items');

ItemsPagination = new Meteor.Pagination(Items, {
    templateName: "ItemsList",
    itemTemplate: "Item",
    divWrapper: 'container',
    infinite: true,
    infiniteTrigger: 0.8,
    pageSizeLimit: 1512,
    dataMargin: 0,
    perPage: 21
});
```

These are the templates used by the pagination object:

```html
<template name="ItemsList">
    {{> pages}}
</template>

<template name="Item">

    <div class="ms-item col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <div class="well clearfix">

            <h4>{{name}}</h4>

            <!-- Using CFS package in a global helper to retrieve the item image -->
            {{#with getPhoto photo}}
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="{{url store='images_items'}}" alt="No photo" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
                </a>
            {{/with}}

            <!-- Using a global helper to get the item category -->
            {{#with getCategory category}}
                <h5 class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"> <a href="#">{{name}}</a> </h5>
            {{/with}}

            <h4 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right"> {{price}} €</h4>

            <div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <!-- Using a global helper to get the item owner -->
                    {{#with getUser owner}}
                        {{#with profile}}
                            <a href="#" class="break-word">
                                {{ [first-name] }} {{ [last-name] }}
                            </a>
                        {{/with}} 
                    {{/with}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

These is the code used by the `ItemList` template:

```js
var observer, container;

Template.ItemList.onRendered(function() {

    container = $('#container');

    //Load Isotope with Masonry
    container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        container.isotope({
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            itemSelector: '.ms-item',
            transitionDuration: '0.1s'
        });

        container.isotope('layout');
    });

    //Using a MutationObserver to readapt the layout when a new item is added
    observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            container.isotope('reloadItems').isotope('layout').isotope();
        });
    });

    //Adding the MutationObserver to the items container
    observer.observe(container.get(0), {
        attributes: false, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: false
    });

});
```

And finally, this is the usage of the template:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        {{> ItemsList}}
    </div>
</template>
```

That's how I made it. Hope this helps someone ;)

**EDIT**

I have found a better way to do all this (without a `MutationObserver` I mean). Instead, I'm using the [`_uihooks`](http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation) object provided by Meteor:

```js
Template.ItemList.onRendered(function() {

    var container = $('#container');

    //Load Isotope with Masonry
    container.imagesLoaded(function() {

        container.isotope({
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            itemSelector: '.ms-item',
            transitionDuration: '0.1s'
        }).isotope('layout').isotope();
    });

    //Using uihooks instead of MutationObserver
    container[0]._uihooks = {

        insertElement: function(node, next) {

            $(node).insertBefore(next);

            container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                container.isotope('reloadItems').isotope('layout').isotope();
            });
        },

        removeElement: function(node, next) {

            $(node).remove();

            container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                container.isotope('reloadItems').isotope('layout').isotope();
            });
        }
    };
});
```